# Python Pandas Data Frame search

Tags: python, pandas

I have code here where I'm searching through a series on a pandas dataframe.

```
                    df[(df['SlyWeekofFiscalYear']==wk) &
                       (df['IB']==bnd) &
                       (df['slyfiscalyear']==yr)]
                    ['Wholesale'].sum()
```

It's in a function that passes a kwarg `bnd=None`. Is there a way to disregard the 2nd line of code if `bnd=None`?

Currently I have a long if statement but I'd like to tidy up the code if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried replacing the second line with some thing that's always `true` if `bnd=None`?

Somelike:

```
((df['IB']==bnd) | (bnd is None))
```

Comment: Perfect - I used your suggestion.

So simple but yet it escaped me!

Answer (score 2):

You can change the second line to `((bnd is None) | (df['IB'] == bnd))`. If `bnd` is None, this produces an all true Series, and since you have `&` operators, it will have no effect on the result.

Comment: Will the second boolean vector be evaluated if the first condition is true?

Comment: @IanS Normally, unlike `or` or `and`. `|` and `&` have no short circuits. But can't find the docs at this moment.

Comment: That's what I suspected. Your word is enough for me :)

Comment: So my solution could be marginally faster!

Comment: @IanS Hmm, I am suspicious how faster it could be though. `|` is vectorized and usually pretty fast.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a ternary statement:

```
(df['IB'] == bnd if bnd is not None else True)
```

The scalar value `True` should be broadcast properly to a vector of the right length.